# STM32 output initial state problem

Tags: stm32, arm, gpio

I am using the STM32 IDE and an STM32F4 board. When I power the board the output pins go high and then go low. How do I prevent this from happening? I want these pins to start low.

Comment: First set the output register to low. Then configure the pin as output pin. For more details, please specify your programming language, the framework (STM32 HAL, Arduino etc.) you're using.

Comment: I assume this is happening when the microcontroller is under reset which is even before any code execution starts. If you attach the datasheets of the board and the micro-controller and show some waveforms, it will be helpful to understand when exactly the issue happens.    During reset micro-controllers try to achieve a low power state by disabling the digital IOs and applying a pullup on the pins. Is this what is happening?